# Best way to implement tearoffs in swift?

Tags: swift

I started coding in Swift only recently and I am hitting an issue. I need a tearoff mechanism for several of my swift classes and I wonder what the best way to implement that. Let me explain: I need to implement an extension for 3 of my 50+ classes. Since the code there will be rarely called by users, I am thinking of a tearoff instead of a subclass to improve memory footprint. For complex architectural reasons, a subclass would not be practical anyway. So the idea is the following: have my three classes host a TearOff? attribute, that is instantiated only when a first method of the extension is called, and call the tearoff from my classes so the code (that is pretty complex) is shared. Skeleton:

```
class foo1 {}

class foo2 {}

class foo3 {}

class TearOff { func method() { blablablabla } }

extension foo1 { func method() {
  if nil == tearoff {
    tearoff = TearOff()
  }
  tearoff!.method()
}

extension foo2 { func method() {
  if nil == tearoff {
    tearoff = TearOff()
  }
  tearoff!.method()
}

extension foo3 { func method() {
  if nil == tearoff {
    tearoff = TearOff()
  }
  tearoff!.method()
}
```

My problem is that an extension can host only methods, and not attributes, so I can't declare the tearoff as a TearOff? in the three extensions. And declaring it directly in foo1 foo2 and foo3, although always possible, is really suboptimal.

I would appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks a lot!

Comment: why need tearoff to be a own class. why not using protocols and extensions only?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich as I said, using a subclass is not practical in my project because I need to strictly follow a protocol/class architecture I have no hands on. A protocol and extension only would imply a replication of my code in the three extensions and I want to avoid that.

Comment: @Thilo a tearoff is a class hosting rarely used part of the logics of another one that you instantiate only when you need it; it's a footprint reduction mechnism.

Comment: i dont get that. use a protocol. let the three classes implement that protocol using a exension ```extension MyClass : MyProt{}```. use an extension to add the logic to the protocol ```extension MyProt{func ....}```